# sql formatting and padding of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I"m trying to format and pad LSD numbers to look like this. 100/14-34-018-09W4/00

sometimes they make look like this 4-9-62-3W6M in the database. i need to format it so it looks like this 100/04-09-62-03W6/00.  Some may or may not be in the format already and if they already have the 100/ or 102 in front for example then ignore that part.

If the first 3 numbers are missing, default to 100 or pad to 100.  Replace the M with '' and the end after the / replace with 00 if nothing or pad 00. Also between in the middle between / and /, there are numbers 14-34 etc. if one of those numbers is 6. pad 0 to the left. so its a -06- instead of 6.

Just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction or the easiest way to accomplish this. thanks

Comment: Which SQL database are you working with? Adding that to your tags will get you better results, since SQL dialects actually vary between major suppliers.

Comment: That looks a lot like business.display logic, not data logic.  I would either do that formatting in the display or business layer or fix your data so no formatting is necessary.  The SQL to do something likt that would be very ugly and hard to debug.

Comment: ya the problem is we scraped data from excel using vb.net and putting it into a database. now that the data is there we don't want to have to rescrap it because it takes like 3 days.  So just wondering if we could query it, format and put it into another column

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think I would approach this in steps.  Before starting, save the table somewhere, so nothing inadvertent happens.

```
update t
    set lsd = lsd + '/00'
    where lsd not like '%/__';

update t
    set lsd = '100/' + lsd
    where lsd not like '%/%/__';
```

Then:

```
update t
    set lsd = stuff(lsd, 5, 0, '0')
    where lsd like '%/_-%';
```

And so on, for each position.  That is build up the accurate string using `where` to fill in one position at a time.  This may take a few minutes, but it is probably a simpler and safer process than trying to do it all in one large query.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES('4-9-62-3W6M')
                        ,('100/4-9-62-3W6M')
                        ,('4-9-62-3W6M/3')
                        ,('102/4-9-62-3W6M')
                        ,('5/4-9-62-3W6/5');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT 
           ID
          ,d.YourString 
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(d.YourString,'/','-'),'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheXML
          ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',d.YourString)>0 AND CHARINDEX('/',d.YourString)<CHARINDEX('-',d.YourString) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS HasPrefix
    FROM @dummy AS d
) 
,Parted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CASE WHEN HasPrefix=1 THEN TheXML.value('(/x)[1]','nvarchar(max)') 
                                 ELSE '100' END AS Prefix
          ,TheXML.value('(/x)[1+sql:column("HasPrefix")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1
          ,TheXML.value('(/x)[2+sql:column("HasPrefix")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2
          ,TheXML.value('(/x)[3+sql:column("HasPrefix")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3
          ,TheXML.value('(/x)[4+sql:column("HasPrefix")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part4
          ,TheXML.value('(/x)[5+sql:column("HasPrefix")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PostFix
    FROM Splitted
)
SELECT REPLACE(STR(Prefix,3),' ','0') + '/'
      +REPLACE(STR(Part1,2),' ','0') + '-'
      +REPLACE(STR(Part2,2),' ','0') + '-'
      +REPLACE(STR(Part3,2),' ','0') + '-'
      +CASE WHEN RIGHT(Part4,1)='M' THEN LEFT(Part4,LEN(Part4)-1) ELSE Part4 END + '/'
      +ISNULL(REPLACE(STR(PostFix,2),' ','0'),'00')
FROM Parted
```

The result

```
100/04-09-62-3W6/00
100/04-09-62-3W6/00
100/04-09-62-3W6/03
102/04-09-62-3W6/00
005/04-09-62-3W6/05
```

### What is going on?

After inserting some test data into a *mock-up* table I use one CTE to split your string at the hyphens. Before this, the slashes are replaced with hyphens, so we get each part separately.

A flag `HasPrefix` tells us, whether the given code has a prefix (like `100/` or not). We use this flag in the second CTE where we retrieve the parts out of the splitted string as add-parameter to find the actual position.

The final `SELECT` will use `STR()` and `REPLACE` for the padding and will concatenate the parts to one single string.

If you want you can set a `SELECT * FROM` at the end to see all the intermediate steps.

Comment: cool, i tried except with the data i have i get error converting nvarchar to float

Comment: @Sirus Is this question solved? Do you need further help? What does *I get error* mean? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!